# Arrange items in the jQuery UI menu widget horizontally

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-menu

How to I arrange the items in the [jQuery UI menu widget](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12137997/Menu) horizontally. It's still in development so things like this haven't been written yet.

Does anyone have a fix?

Comment: Have you tried to do this and not succeeded ?

Comment: Do you have sub-menu items, or anything fancy like that?

Answer (score 0):

When I view the site it is broken.
However usually with these things you can try to assign a class to the item and float:left the class.

Comment: Demo is at http://jsfiddle.net/cNgG5/ Move cursor to Category and single column menu appears. How to render it to multiple columns ?